# Calculated Column: Combine 3 Coulmns only if 4th Column Value is True

Tags: 2010, calculated-column

I have created a Calculated Column that combines 3 other columns. The Formula for that is

```
=[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title]
```

And this works.

Now I want to do the same thing, but only if certain conditions are true.

The result needs to be =[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title], but only if the column [Delivery Status]= Active OR Under Development OR Under Revision. If none of those conditions are true, then move on to the next item for processing.

I tried all of the Formulas below, but all give syntax errors probably because IF statements in calculated columns require a TRUE and FALSE response. But, I don't know what to enter for the negative response, if all I am looking for is a positive response.

```
=IF(OR([Delivery Status]='Active',[Delivery Status]='Under Development',[Delivery Status]='Under Revision',[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title],""))

=IF(OR([Delivery Status]='Active',[Delivery Status]='Under Development',[Delivery Status]='Under Revision',[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title]))

=IF(OR([Delivery Status]='Active',[Delivery Status]='Under Development',[Delivery Status]='Under Revision'),[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title])

=IF(([Delivery Status]='Active',OR([Delivery Status]='Under Development'),OR([Delivery Status]='Under Revision')),([Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title])

=IF(OR([Delivery Status]='Active',OR([Delivery Status]='Under Development'),OR([Delivery Status]='Under Revision')),([Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title])

=IF([Delivery Status]='Active'),[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title],=IF([Delivery Status]='Under Development'),[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title],=IF([Delivery Status]='Under Revision'),[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title]

=IF([Delivery Status]='Active',[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title],=IF([Delivery Status]='Under Development',[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title],=IF([Delivery Status]='Under Revision',[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title])))
```

Comment: `=IF(OR([Delivery Status]="Active",[Delivery Status]="Under Development",[Delivery Status]="Under Revision"),[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title]," ")`

Comment: Now the column shows several blank lines. Is there a way to hide or remove those lines those lines after the column is populated, or while it is being populated?

Comment: Aren't these Crs Code, Crs Number, Crs Title required fields?

Comment: Crs Code, Crs Number, Crs Title are being use to create the CC. The CC ends up with several hundred blank entries. I didn't explain my problem fully in my original post. I am using this column in another list as a CHOICE column with a data source. I was able to reduce the number of blank entries to 1 by enabling unique values, but still have that one list item. Not a huge deal if I make it 'zzz' so it goes to the bottom, but not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Third formula you are using is quite accurate, just need to make some modifications. Try using below formula:

```
=IF(OR([Delivery Status]="Active",[Delivery Status]="Under Development",[Delivery Status]="Under Revision"),[Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title]," ")
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh! I wish I could set both answers as correct. But since mike provided the Excel tool, I gave it to him. ;-)

Comment: Welcome. More important is you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but the parens are in the wrong places. ORs do return a True or False.

```
=IF(
    OR([Delivery Status]='Active',
       [Delivery Status]='Under Development',
       [Delivery Status]='Under Revision'
   ),
  [Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title],
  ""
 )
```

or with some comments:

```
=IF(                                          the IF statement
    OR([Delivery Status]='Active',            the True/False test
       [Delivery Status]='Under Development',    (if any of these
       [Delivery Status]='Under Revision'         are true...)
   ),                                         end of the OR
  [Crs Code]&[Crs Number]&": "&[Crs Title],   what to return if True
  ""                                          what to return if False
 )                                            end of the IF
```

The easiest way to write and debug these formulas is by using Excel:  http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/08/sharepoint-creating-calculated-column.html